# How to use like sumifs with an OR logic among all criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do like this in VBA,

```
range(A1).formula = "Sumifs(SumRange, {Crteria_1,Crteria_range_1} OR {Crteria_2,Crteria_range_2}, ...)
```

I want to use Sum with multiple condition, and if any one of conditions is met, then the Corresponding value is added.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ965.png)

Comment: use SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT(SumRange*((Criteria_range_1 = Criteria_1)+(Criteria_range_2 = Criteria_2)>0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks for the input!
I tried, and found it was still wrong.
But when those part are separate it went well, Any keywords should I search for?
I have updated the pic on the post.